# is there anyway to change background image (not color) of button from xml in android studio 4.2.2?

Tags: android, android-studio

I am using android studio 4.2.2
when I try to change button background image with xml.
my code is below

```
       <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_ok"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/btn_background"
        android:text="@string/ok"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/btn_cancel"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.3" />
```

this was working for the previous version of android studio.
but now the buttons's background is always purple.
any additional setting needed?

Comment: use `app:backgroundTint="your color"`.

Comment: I know it but how can I set image as background?

Comment: Where did you mention in your question that you need to set an image as background? You said background color.

Comment: i just edited it. but my code was android:background="@drawable/btn_background"

Comment: when I am using android studio 3.1, my code or your link code was working. this is problem when I using latest version of android studio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code

```
 <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
            android:id="@+id/btn_ok"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/btn_background"
            android:text="@string/ok"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/btn_cancel"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.3"/>
```

Comment: yeah, it's working but why i can't do with <Button>? what is better?

Comment: For a Button, the primary color defined in the app theme overrides any custom background you want to apply to a Button, but it is not the case for the AppCompatButton.So you can use "AppCompatButton"instead of Button.